Error SQL S1093 al ejecutar un Store Procedure desde Java
Por que al intentar llamar a un Store Procedure desde un microservicio obtengo un error de Sql-server diciendo

El parámetro USERIBSTMP no estaba definido para el procedimiento almacenado InsertarUsuariosConCodigoTest2.

, el cual no me permite continuar pero cuando ejecuto el store procedure en la misma base de datos, no obtengo el mismo error; adjunto el error y las clases que utilizo; cabe mencionar que ya intent'e cambiar de nombre los parametros, tambien el valor que usan, tambien creando un StoredProcedure de un parametro y sigo recibiendo el mismo error.
Error en la consola:
2024-11-22 13:13:01.415  WARN 26040 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1093
2024-11-22 13:13:01.416 ERROR 26040 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : El parámetro USERIBSTMP no estaba definido para el procedimiento almacenado InsertarUsuariosConCodigoTest2.
2024-11-22 13:13:01.490 ERROR 26040 --- [oundedElastic-1] p.p.s.c.p.c.s.impl.CampaignServiceImpl   : Error procesando el registro de los clientes: Error preparing registered callable parameter; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error preparing registered callable parameter
2024-11-22 13:13:01.499 ERROR 26040 --- [oundedElastic-1] p.p.s.c.p.c.s.impl.CampaignServiceImpl   : Error procesando la lista de clientes para el cupón de descuento
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error preparing registered callable parameter; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error preparing registered callable parameter
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoLiftFuseable] :
reactor.core.publisher.Mono.fromCallable(Mono.java:532)
pe.pichincha.services.channel.preferencesecurity.campaign.service.impl.CampaignServiceImpl.processCouponRequest(CampaignServiceImpl.java:134)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__Mono.fromCallable ⇢ at pe.pichincha.services.channel.preferencesecurity.campaign.service.impl.CampaignServiceImpl.processCouponRequest(CampaignServiceImpl.java:134)
|_  Mono.subscribeOn ⇢ at pe.pichincha.services.channel.preferencesecurity.campaign.service.impl.CampaignServiceImpl.processCouponRequest(CampaignServiceImpl.java:142)
*_______Mono.flatMap ⇢ at pe.pichincha.services.channel.preferencesecurity.campaign.service.impl.CampaignServiceImpl.registerClientCoupon(CampaignServiceImpl.java:69)
|_    Mono.doOnError ⇢ at pe.pichincha.services.channel.preferencesecurity.campaign.service.impl.CampaignServiceImpl.registerClientCoupon(CampaignServiceImpl.java:80)

Original Stack Trace:
Clase de Servicio:
  @Slf4j
  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  @Transactional
  public class CampaignServiceImpl implements CampaignService {
    private final CampaignClientRepository campaignClientRepository;
    private Mono<ClientCouponResponse> processCouponRequest(ClientCouponRequest clientCoupon) {

    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        String ibsClients = String.join(",", clientCoupon.getIbsClient());
        campaignClientRepository.insertCoupons(ibsClients, clientCoupon.getCouponCode());

        return ClientCouponResponse.builder()
                .codeStatus(Constants.STATUS_SUCCESS_COUPON)
                .description("ibsClients insert successfully into DB")
                .build();
     }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
   }
}

Clase interfas:
public interface CampaignClientRepository extends JpaRepository<UserDiscountCampaignTmp, Integer> {  

  @Procedure(name = "InsertarUsuariosConCodigoTest2")    
  void insertCoupons(@Param("USERIBSTMP") String userIbsTmp, @Param("COUPONCODE") String couponCode);
}

Clase Entidad:
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(        
  name = "InsertarUsuariosConCodigoTest2",        
  procedureName = "InsertarUsuariosConCodigoTest2",        
  parameters = {                
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "USERIBSTMP", type = String.class),               
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "COUPONCODE", type = String.class)        
  }
)
@Table(name = "user_discount_campaign_tmp", schema = "prueba")
public class UserDiscountCampaignTmp {    
  @Id    
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
  @Column(name ="USERIDTMP")    
  private int userIdTmp;    

  @Column(name ="USERIBSTMP")    
  private String userIbsTmp;    

  @Column(name ="COUPONCODE")    
   private String couponCode;
}

Stored Procedure:
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertarUsuariosConCodigoTest2(    
  @USERIBSTMP NVARCHAR(50),    
  @COUPONCODE NVARCHAR(50) 
)
AS
BEGIN    
  SET NOCOUNT ON;    
  BEGIN TRY        
    -- Insertar en la tabla destino        
    INSERT INTO user_discount_campaign_tmp (USERIBSTMP, COUPONCODE)        
    VALUES( @USERIBSTMP, @COUPONCODE);    
  END TRY    
  BEGIN CATCH        
    -- Manejo de errores        
    DECLARE @ErrorMsg NVARCHAR(4000), @ErrorSeverity INT, @ErrorState INT;        
    SELECT            
      @ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),            
      @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),            
      @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();        
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMsg, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);    
  END CATCH
END;


¿El usuario que ejecuta la SP qué permisos tiene? Según esto, dicho usuario debe tener el permiso EXECUTE. Puede que ese sea el motivo del error, pues los parámetros están bien definidos.

tienes razon; puede que no tenga permisos, porque trato de ver los roles que tengo asignado y tampoco puedo verlos; voya  solicitar permisos, pruebo y vere si funciona, gracias n.n
